# Route not defined in form action in laravel 7

Tags: laravel

**View Form**

[Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KfMf.png)

**Routes**

[Routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaS8O.png)

**Route list**

[Route list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJKct.png)

**Controller**

[Reg controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19QJy.png)

**ERROR**

Route [] not defined.

Comment: <form method="post" action = "{{route('student.store')}}">

Comment: You have probably cached your routes. Try to run ```php artisan route:clear```.

Comment: Totally unrelated, but quick tip: In PHP try to use single quotes `'` where possible, instead of `"`.  Double quotes are parsed, meaning they take up more processing power.  :)

Comment: Clear your route as **Kurt Friars** said, if still face the problem then run `php artisan route:list` and post the output in your question

Comment: I tried clearing the cache still got the same error

Comment: @CuriousCoder `php artisan view:clear`

Comment: Still the same error. I just don't understand what's wrong

Comment: If you faced the same problem, then edit your question with your full route codes and blade `form` code

Comment: @STA I have updated the question.

Comment: Try with `action="/student"`

Comment: @STA Not working still the same issue

Comment: `Route [] not defined.` on which page which line?

Comment: It actually throws exception so it doesn't point at a particular line

Answer (score 0):

if you use `resource`

```
{{ route('student.store') }}
```

if you use `->name("student")`

```
{{ route('student') }}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to read carefully the laravel [documentation for routes](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing)

The form action attribute specifies where to send the form-data when a form is submitted.
so you simply direct submitted data as follow :

```
<form method="POST" action="student/store">
```

provided that your route like :

```
Route::post("student/store", "RegStudentsController@store");
```

or if you want to use the route:

```
Route::post("/student", "RegStudentsController@store")->name("student");

<form method="POST" action="{{ route('student') }}">
```

**Update**

as per your updated screen shoots the solution will be doing something like:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ url('/student') }}">
```

Comment: I did the same thing check my route:list you'll see

Comment: you update your question much bro, it's prefered to write code not screenshots, how ever I reviewed your code it seems all good may be you cached your routes from earlier so please run `php artisan route:clear` then `php artisan cache:clear`